# How to merge JSON two indexes and then Parse information

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to iterate both index of **JSON**(Players and Buildings), so that i can a get new result in **jQuery**

I have two index of **JSON** one having information of Players and second index having information of Building related Player.

I want to Parse it so that i can get Player and its building name.

**My Actual JSON result**

```
{
        "Players": [
            {
                "id": "35",
                "building_id": "8",
                "room_num": "101",
            },
            {
                "id": "36",
                "building_id": "9",
                "room_num": "102",
            },
            {
                "id": "37",
                "building_id": "10",
                "room_num": "103",
            },
            {
                "id": "38",
                "building_id": "11",
                "room_num": "104",
            }
        ],
        "Buildings": [
            {
                "id": "8",
                "name": "ABC"
            },
            {
                "id": "9",
                "name": "DEF"
            },
            {
                "id": "10",
                "name": "GHI"
            },
            {
                "id": "11",
                "name": "JKL"
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Need this**

```
 "information": [
                {
                    "player_id": "35",
                    "Buildings_name": "ABC"
                },
                {
                    "player_id": "36",
                    "Buildings_name": "DEF"
                },
                {
                    "player_id": "37",
                    "Buildings_name": "GHI"
                },
                {
                    "player_id": "38",
                    "Buildings_name": "JKL"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you link those information fields on DB side?

Comment: Hmm ok. thankx for suggestion. i did not tried this at DB Side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, this go for each player and check if there are buildings and will map them to new structure. This will not filter values for buildings that do not have mapping to players, and will not include the buildings with no players.

```
var x = {
    "Players": [
        {
            "id": "35",
            "building_id": "8",
            "room_num": "101",
        },
        {
            "id": "36",
            "building_id": "9",
            "room_num": "102",
        },
        {
            "id": "37",
            "building_id": "10",
            "room_num": "103",
        },
        {
            "id": "38",
            "building_id": "11",
            "room_num": "104",
        }
    ],
    "Buildings": [
        {
            "id": "8",
            "name": "ABC"
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "name": "DEF"
        },
        {
            "id": "10",
            "name": "GHI"
        },
        {
            "id": "11",
            "name": "JKL"
        }
    ]
};

var res = $.map(x.Players, function(item) {
    return {
        player_id: item.id,
        building_name: $.grep(x.Buildings, function(i) {
            return i.id == item.building_id
        }).length != 0 ? $.grep(x.Buildings, function(i) {
            return i.id == item.building_id
        })[0].name : undefined
    }
})
```

and if you want to filter values that do not have relationships e.g INNER join

```
var resInnerJoin = $.grep($.map(x.Players, function(item) {
    return {
        player_id: item.id,
        building_name: $.grep(x.Buildings, function(i) {
            return i.id == item.building_id
        }).length != 0 ? $.grep(x.Buildings, function(i) {
            return i.id == item.building_id
        })[0].name : undefined
    }
}), function(it) {
    return it.building_name != undefined
})
```

Comment: ok thankyou. it is giving me 
building_id and player_id. But in need Building name instead of Building id

Comment: @Biker fixed, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it in PHP :

```
$json = '{...}';

// create and PHP array with you json data.
$array = json_decode($json, true);

// make an array with buildings informations and with building id as key
$buildings = array();
foreach( $array['Buildings'] as $b ) $buildings[$b['id']] = $b;


$informations = array();

for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count($array['Players']) ; $i++ )
{
    $informations[$i] = array(
        'player_id' => $array['Players'][$i]['id'],
        'Buildings_name' => $buildings[$array['Players'][$i]['building_id']]['name']
    );
}

$informations = json_encode($informations);

var_dump($informations);
```

Comment: nice thankx for you suggestion. i will try .. :) and i think this could be better on server side.

Comment: hi djidi can we chat? .. i need help with your code.. its pretty and too nice code.